# How to skip executing a single service with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have `docker-compose.yml` file with a set of services inside. In some cases for development I want docker not to start on of services which is a helper one when I run `docker-compose up`.

Is it possible to do and if so, how to?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is still not implemented yet, see the discussion [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1896).

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be to add a profile to the service

[Using profiles with Compose | Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/)

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  someservice:
    image: someimage
    profiles: [profile-to-exclude]
```

If all the rest of the services have no profile assigned, then all services except for the one with a profile will be run.

```bash
docker compose up -d
```

Runs all services except the one with a profile.